# How to properly call AWS Lambda Function from API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, guzzle

I was messing with Lambda recently, and finally got my lambda code running properly. Or at least when I test it using the "Test" from the Lambda page itself, where I can write my JSON by hand.

I need to run this function through API Request, so in my server I was expecting to make a POST request with the JSON data I had in my "Test" before. Turns out it returns me a 502 server error. I`ve tried to test it using the Amazon API Request page, where I can test by choosing the request TYPE, body, queryStrings and so on. And still did not work.

I had a earlier version of this lambda function working with guzzle before. It just required GET parameters, and it was quite simple to setup using guzzle in PHP.

I think this should be very simple and I'm missing something.

Thanks!

```
info = $guzzle->post('https://my-secret-url.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/lambda-function-name', [
            'query' =>
            [
                'out' => 'lambda/piperun.pdf',
                'in' => 'invoice,propostas_7_5.pdf'
            ],
            'json' => $this->proposta->getJSONData() //Same JSON from image
        ]);
```

[image: Test that works for me. I tried to send the same content through a POST request and it did not behave]

[image: Does not work trying myself]

[image: On the AWS test works fine same request]

Comment: You Lambda function is throwing errors, resulting in the 502 response. You need to check your Lambda function's logs to see what the issue is.

Comment: Is your lambda function running off of the handwritten JSON or off of the actual request parameters?

Comment: I use the **event** variable to get data inside the function. I just uploaded two images showing my tests. The one at AWS API now works, but when I try to replicate I still get 502